# Adding fields in doucuments mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How can I add a new field to every document in an existent collection?

I know how to update an existing document's field but not how to add a new field to every document in a collection. How can I do this in the mongodb compass?

Comment: Compass is not really a good tool for updating many records.  Instead, simply connect using mongosh and issue an update command.  You can use Compass to update single documents by editing them in the GUI and saving them but that is one record at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Open your compass and connect to your cluster. Then open mongosh (`_mongosh`) at the bottom of the window. Switch to your target database and then type in the terminal:

```
db.your_target_collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {field_name: null}})
```

This adds the field `field_name` and initialized the new field to a value or to `null`.